# send mail over smtp with-out mail limit c#

Tags: c#, email, gmail

i am working about a little project, and i have an issue.

I have a class that responsible for sending emails over Smtp protocol using Gmail.

The class working just fine, **but i faced in front a limit of sending only 20 mails per hour.**

means, if i want to send 21 mails in a single run, only 20 mails will sent, and the 21 mail won't.

i was tried to look for other host for sending mail through but no luck. 
(like yahoo, outlook..)

i hope you guys maybe faced this problem and may help me get over it.

(maybe other host, or change the code..)

thanks,
Yossi.

Comment: Seems to me like you need to find a different provider - which makes this off topic I think

Comment: what do u mean? @ste-fu